# How to handle PDO transaction errors to inform to the client the result of it?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, error-handling

As you know, a transaction is composed of multiple prepared statements that is executed one by one, if one of that statements fails, it will throw a PDOException, you can catch it and get the error message, but this error message is for the "developer", I need to show an specific error to the final user like: "The transaction failed because ....", that '....' is the reason I need to show to the client.

I have an idea to solve this and it is using an array named `'query_trace'`, that array will put a key for the executed query and a result of that execution like:

```
// prepare statement, bindParams.... 
    $query_trace['query1_insert_user'] = "OK"

// prepare statement, bindParams.... 
    $query_trace['query2_insert_user_more_information'] = "OK"

// prepare statement, bindParams.... 
    $query_trace['query3_create_user_account'] = "FAILED"
```

(That FAILED string is stablished in the catch:

```
    } catch (PDOException $e) 
{ $query_trace['query3_create_user_account'] = "FAILED" } 
return $query_trace; ...
```

Then in the controller when I get the query_trace response, I will check:

```
if ($query_trace['query1_insert_user'] != "OK")
   echo "The data for the user is not valid";
else
if ($query_trace['query2_insert_user_more_information'] != "OK")
   echo "The additional information of the user is not valid";
else
if ($query_trace['query3_create_user_account'] != "OK")
   echo "The username is not valid or actually exists";
else
   echo "The transaction was great!";
```

The question is that this is a good way and/or PDO offers some functions/methods to "auto-trace" this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by error messages, you don't need neither a transaction nor multiple statements.

Just validate the user input before doing any inserts, then insert the user data *into a single user talbe*, without any transactions.

The only possible case that you would want to report to a user is a duplicate username. In this particular case you may want to catch the error, check whether it's a duplicate key, and if so - report that report to the user. Otherwise just re-throw the exception and *let a site-wider error-handler to tell a user that something went wrong.*

Comment: You should actually do a transaction when you have rows to insert in multiple tables: what if the MySQL shuts down or goes away during the process? You'll end up with half-saved data, no matter whether they were valid.

Comment: But you don't need multiple tables. You need only one. Do not overcomplicate things. But in case when you really need a transaction, then you don't need a special error message for a user anyway. There is no point telling them that half of their data was processed - it would be both misleading and wrong. Just send them the general 500 error instead

Comment: Still, your "more user info" table is peculiar, to say the least

Comment: that is an example to show what I want to do, I believe the transactions is necessary, and I'm using it. I believe the solution is validate all first, I don't see another way.

Answer (score 0):

This makes little sense since a transaction turns a bunch of request to one "atomic" request. So trying to get information about the sub atomic elements is quiet odd.

So I'm not aware of any "easy way" to do so.

You may also do a `SELECT` before every statement (but it might get tricky if the `SELECT` is the statement that failed). It would probably work for `PROCEDURE` too.

```
SELECT "The user creation failed";
INSERT INTO user (...) VALUES (?,...,?);
SELECT "The user subinfos save failed";
INSERT INTO user_subinfos...;
```

Note that user will only know which statement failed, not why it failed.